# What is the average number of legs per human?

Tags: biology

Someone told me that the average number of legs in the human population is less than 2, because there are more amputees than those with multiple limbs. I found it odd at the time (a statistics teacher told me it), but now it got me thinking. Has anyone *actually* measured this?

Comment: I'd say you didn't need to; it's logic that dictates more people have amputations, than have deformaties leading to extra legs, so it follows that the average number of legs is less than 2.

Comment: What's even freakier, the average number of testicles in the human population is not just less than 2, but actually somewhere around 1!

Comment: Consider: When a child is born with three or four legs, rare as it is in itself, the physiological explanation is very often a conjoined twin. It is not immediately obvious that a conjoined twin with three legs total, should be considered to affect the leg/individual mean in a positive direction.

Comment: @David that means the average human ALSO has one half of a vagina!

Comment: @Monkey Oh the possibilities!

Comment: @David : the number of monorchid man is a difficult statistic to have correct between congenital, accidental and surgical cases.

Comment: Mean != Median and questions like this are why tracking _both_ is useful.

Comment: @sal I'm pretty sure it's mean. The median is most likely 2. (Please don't take over the world and order everyone to cut of one of their legs just to prove me wrong. *I'm* the one who's supposed to do that.)

Comment: @muntoo the Mean number of legs might be 1.999_ while the Median number is 2. I was suggesting that the question assumes the use of Mean where Median is more appropriate.

Comment: @sal *Why* is median more appropriate? I doubt that that's what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 11):

[This fact-sheet](http://www.amputee-coalition.org/fact_sheets/amp_stats_cause.html) from the [Amputee Coalition of America](http://www.amputee-coalition.org/) should have the figures you need to approximate the average.

> In the United States, there are approximately 1.7 million people living with limb loss. It is estimated that one out of every 200 people in the U.S. has had an amputation.

Many of those without limbs are missing arms, not legs. To figure out the number of missing legs, you will need to do a bit of data-crunching - they have figures of upper versus lower-body limbs, but they are generally not given per capita, but per hospital discharge, by cause, so you will need to multiply these out.

Further, if a person has multiple amputations of the same limb (at different points) that will confuse the averages, but that should be close enough for your needs.

(When you have finished using their figures, perhaps you should consider donating to the organisation that produced them.)

Comment: These statistics are interesting. BTW, I should correct "funny"; I never intended to be offensive (I was in a rush when I wrote the post.)

Comment: You can cut off your left arm *twice?*

Comment: @muntoo: Yes, at the forearm, and then the elbow (for example).